# calculate rate of attribute by id sql

Tags: sql, primary-key, rate

First, this is my table schema:

```
order_id, product_id, add_to_cart_order, reordered
```

My problem is calculate the rate of reordered by product. So we can see "add_to_cart_order" is useless, I don't know for "order_id". "reordered" can be have '1' and '0' value.

For the moment, I can have the count of "reordored" by product_id with

```
SELECT 
    product_id, 
    COUNT(reordered) 
FROM 
    train 
WHERE
    reordered = '1' 
GROUP BY 
    product_id;
```

and the count of occurrence of a product with

```
SELECT 
    product_id, COUNT(*) 
FROM
    train  
GROUP BY 
    product_id;
```

I tried

```
SELECT 
    t1.product_id, 
    COUNT(t1.product_id) / (SELECT COUNT(reordered) 
                            FROM train t2 
                            WHERE t2.reordered = '1' 
                              AND t1.product_id = t2.product_id 
                            GROUP BY product_id) 
FROM
    train t1 
GROUP BY
    t1.product_id;
```

But it takes too much time (I don't know if it's the right request because I don't have results yet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT Product_id, SUM(CASE WHEN reordered=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) /
COUNT(*) AS ReorderedRate
FROM
train
GROUP BY Product_id
```

Comment: Your solution and @vignesh-kumar-a 's answer is right. I had to add some adjustments, this is my final request: ```SELECT Product_id, SUM(CASE WHEN reordered='1' THEN 100 ELSE 0 END ) /
COUNT(*) AS ReorderedRate
FROM
train
GROUP BY Product_id;```

Answer (score 1):

Try this elegant

```
SELECT t1.product_id, SUM(CASE WHEN reordered = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(t1.product_id)
FROM train t1 
GROUP BY t1.product_id;
```

Comment: Your solution and @DCSQL777 's answer is right. I had to add some adjustments, this is my final request: SELECT Product_id, SUM(CASE WHEN reordered='1' THEN 100 ELSE 0 END ) / COUNT(*) AS ReorderedRate FROM train GROUP BY Product_id;

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest method is to use `AVG()`:

```
SELECT product_id, 
       AVG(CASE WHEN reordered = '1' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END) 
FROM train 
GROUP BY product_id;
```

If reordered is really a number that only takes on the values `0` and `1`, then you can further simplify this to either:

```
SELECT product_id, AVG(reordered)
FROM train 
GROUP BY product_id;
```

or:

```
SELECT product_id, AVG(reordered * 1.0)
FROM train 
GROUP BY product_id;
```

The second is needed in databases where the average of an integer is returned as an integer.

Comment: @Picot . . . I answered because I think this is a better answer than your currently accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

this will compute for each `product_id` :
    the number of lines in train  `cnt_prod`
    the number of lines in train  `cnt_prod_reorder` that was reordered

```
SELECT t1.product_id, COUNT(t1.product_id) as cnt_prd,
                      COUNT(case when t.1.reordered='1' then  1 else NULL end ) as cnt_prd_reord 
from train t1 group by t1.product_id;
```

So after you can do  :

```
select st.product_id , st.cnt_prd , st.cnt_prd / st.cnt_prd_reord
from (
     SELECT t1.product_id, COUNT(t1.product_id) as cnt_prd,
                           COUNT(case when t.1.reordered='1' then  1 else NULL end   ) as cnt_prd_reord 
     from train t1 group by t1.product_id 
) as st ;
```

Comment: I have this error with your solution: "derived tables not supported" but now my request works with others answers